# C/C++ How to read file to char array for encrypting

Tags: c++, file, encryption, aes

I have a simple implementation of AES (CTR Mode, which allows encrypting/decrypting more than 16bytes)

And I want to read a file to a char array and then to encrypt it.
I have tried the following, without success:

```
long GetFileSize(const char* filePath)
{
FILE* pFile = fopen(filePath, "rb");

if (pFile == NULL)
{
    printf("error");
    getchar();
}
fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
long lSize = ftell(pFile);
rewind(pFile);
fclose(pFile);

return lSize;
}


// Reads given file to buffer, and returns pointer to that buffer.
// Caller should free this memory later.
unsigned char * ReadFile(const char * filePath)
{
FILE * pFile;
long lSize;
unsigned char * buffer;
size_t result;

pFile = fopen(filePath, "rb");
if (pFile == NULL) { fputs("File error", stderr); ; }

// obtain file size:
fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell(pFile);
rewind(pFile);

// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize);
if (buffer == NULL) { fputs("Memory error", stderr); ; }

// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);
if (result != lSize) { fputs("Reading error", stderr); ; }

// terminate
fclose(pFile);

// the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. Return pointer to data.
return buffer;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//All char arrays are null terminated here...
uchar szkey[KEY_128] = "very strong key";

const char *filePath = "key.txt";

// Get file size which must be encrypted
long originalSize = GetFileSize(filePath);

// Make this size multiple of block size (16 bytes).
long multipleSize = (originalSize / 16 + 1) * 16;

// Store number of bytes that were needed for padding.
int nrOfPaddingBytes = (int)(multipleSize - originalSize);

// Now, read the file.
unsigned char * fileContents = ReadFile(filePath);

// Create a large buffer to store file contents (including padding bytes),
// and copy file contents to it.
unsigned char * buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(multipleSize);
memcpy(buffer, fileContents, originalSize);

// Allocate space for ciphertext also (should also have size multiple of 8).
unsigned char * ciphertext = (unsigned char*)malloc(multipleSize);
char* cipherhex = (char*)malloc(multipleSize * 2);
char* decryptedhex = (char*)malloc(multipleSize);
unsigned char* dechex = (unsigned char*)malloc(multipleSize);

// Delete old file buffer.
free(fileContents);
fileContents = NULL;

// Pad the plaintext
for (int i = 0; i < nrOfPaddingBytes; i++)
{
    buffer[originalSize + i] = nrOfPaddingBytes;
}

aes_ctx_t *ctx;
u64 nonce;

virtualAES::initialize();
ctx = virtualAES::allocatectx(szkey, sizeof(szkey));
virtualAES::rand_nonce(&nonce);

//encrypt
virtualAES::encrypt_ctr(ctx, buffer, ciphertext, sizeof(buffer), nonce);
cout << "cipherdata in ansi:\n" << ciphertext << "\n\n";
virtualAES::strtohex(ciphertext, cipherhex, originalSize);
cout << "cipherdata in hex:\n" << cipherhex << "\n\n";
return 0;
}
```

but it fails for some reason. Could someone provide me an algorithm to read a file for encrypting?

Comment: `but it fails for some reason` Fails where and how? What did you discover while debugging?

Comment: It does not crash or anything, it just encrypts and decrypts a small part of the input file.

Comment: You pass `sizeof(buffer)` to `virtualAES::encrypt_ctr`. You seem to believe this gives the size of the block of memory that `buffer` points to. That is not the case - `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the pointer, typically 4 or 8.

Comment: Well how do I get the sizeof buffer then?

Comment: It works like a charm when encrypting regular text.

Comment: `how do I get the sizeof buffer then?` You have just allocated it. Surely you know what size it is.

Comment: Why are you padding for a mode of encryption that turns AES into a stream cipher?